# I have three image view; all redirected to same activity using onClick.how can i get which of these is responsible to start the new activity?

Tags: android

```
imageView1 : onclick


Intent slave1_permission = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AddPermissions.class);
                startActivity(slave1_permission);

imageView2. onclick         


Intent slave2_permission = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AddPermissions.class);
                startActivity(slave2_permission);

imageView3.OnClick          


Intent slave3_permission = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AddPermissions.class);
                startActivity(slave3_permission);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple. All you need is to send the id of the ImageView in the extras while starting the activity. Something like this.

```
public void onClick(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddPermissions.class);
    intent.putExtra("activityStartedBy", "First_Image_View");
    //Or any other unique specifier
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and in the activity `onCreate(Bundle bundle)` you can easily extract this variable to know who called this activity

```
@Override
public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String startedBy = (String) bundle.get("activityStartedBy");
        switch(startedBy){
        //TODO: Do whatever you need to do
        }
}
```

Let me know, if you need help.